# Get all Home Hubs available in HomeKit(in iOS 10)

Tags: homekit, ios-homekit

I'm work on HomeKit App and my requirement is to get Home Hubs available in HomeKit(in iOS 10) and there respective states i.e., "connected" or "not connected". I searched in homekit FrameWork but, i didn't find any help Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Did you find an answer?